# Plan executor error during findAndModify :: caused by :: Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id' error

Tags: mongodb-compass

Plan executor error during findAndModify :: caused by :: Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id' error show in mongodb compass during change id type

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.